# Django Authentication Form not authenticating and redirecting

Tags: python, django

**After I put the correct password, it should redirect to "/articles"** , BUT IT'S REFRESHING THE LOGIN PAGE ONLY.

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = a_form(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('/articles')
    else:
        form = a_form()
        context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)
```

This is what my html looks like:
    {% extends 'articles/base.html' %}

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form class="login" action="{%url 'login'%}">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {{form}}
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I wonder what is that I'm missing here.

Comment: Well where do you log in the user? `a_form` is valid, but that's it. Unless you have implemented some logic in `a_form` (which we do not see, it will not do anything).

Comment: Hi,

from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm as a_form

Anyways, issue got fixed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I missed out the **method='post'** in my html file.
Fixed it! :

```
<form class="login" action="{%url 'login'%}" method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```